# Xamarin Forms Image AspectFill isn't working correctly

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Can anyone tell me why this image isn't filling the screen? Is there a known bug with "AspectFill" on Android emulators?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HelloWorld2.AbsoluteLayout_Exercise2">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image Source="AbsoluteLayout_Exercise2.jpeg" `Aspect="AspectFill"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: Code sample and picture of emulation]

Comment: Aspect specifies how the image data will fill the image control.  If you want the Image control to fill the screen, use HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions

Comment: Thanks Jason! It was one of those moments where I just wasn't thinking it all the way through. I resolved it myself a few minutes after posting.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to leverage the AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds to scale the image. I now have the desired result.

```
    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Image Source="AbsoluteLayout_Exercise2.jpeg" Aspect="AspectFill" 
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1"
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```